# SwitchToThread/Thread.Yield vs. Thread.Sleep(0) vs. Thead.Sleep(1)

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to write the ultimate "Yield" method to yield the current time slice to other threads. So far I have found that there are several different ways to make the thread yield its allocated time slice. I just want to make sure I am interpreting them correctly since the documentation is not very clear. So, from what I have read on stackoverflow, MSDN and various blog posts, the following options exist that all have different advantages / disadvantages:

**`SwitchToThread`** [win32] / **`Thread.Yield`** [.NET 4 Beta 1]: yields to any thread on same processor

- Advantage: about twice as fast as
  `Thread.Sleep(0)`
- Disadvantage: yields only to threads
  on same processor

**`Thread.Sleep(0)`:** yields to any thread of same or higher priority on any processor

- Advantage: faster than
  `Thread.Sleep(1)`
- Disadvantage: yields only to threads
  of same or higher priority

**`Thread.Sleep(1)`**: yields to any thread on any processor

- Advantage: yields to any thread on
  any processor
- Disadvantage: slowest option
  (`Thread.Sleep(1)` will usually
  suspend the thread by about 15ms if
  `timeBeginPeriod`/`timeEndPeriod`
  [win32] are not used)

What about `Thread.SpinWait`? Can that be used for yielding the time slice of the thread? If not, what is it used for?

I there something else I have missed or incorrectly interpreted. I'd be grateful if you could correct / add to my understanding.

This is how my Yield method looks like so far:

```
public static class Thread
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SwitchToThread();

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    internal static extern uint timeBeginPeriod(uint period);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    internal static extern uint timeEndPeriod(uint period);

    /// <summary>  yields time slice of current thread to specified target threads </summary>
    public static void YieldTo(ThreadYieldTarget threadYieldTarget)
    {
        switch (threadYieldTarget) {
            case ThreadYieldTarget.None: 
                break; 
            case ThreadYieldTarget.AnyThreadOnAnyProcessor:
                timeBeginPeriod(1); //reduce sleep to actually 1ms instead of system time slice with is around 15ms
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); 
                timeEndPeriod(1); //undo
                break;
            case ThreadYieldTarget.SameOrHigherPriorityThreadOnAnyProcessor:
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0); 
                break;
            case ThreadYieldTarget.AnyThreadOnSameProcessor:
                SwitchToThread();
                break;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("threadYieldTarget");
        }
    }
}

public enum ThreadYieldTarget
{
    /// <summary>  Operation system will decide when to interrupt the thread </summary>
    None,
    /// <summary>  Yield time slice to any other thread on any processor </summary>
    AnyThreadOnAnyProcessor,
    /// <summary>  Yield time slice to other thread of same or higher piority on any processor </summary>
    SameOrHigherPriorityThreadOnAnyProcessor,
    /// <summary> Yield time slice to any other thread on same processor </summary>
    AnyThreadOnSameProcessor
}
```

Comment: Do you mind me asking what class of problems you envisage that this library will solve?

Comment: How about `if(!Thread.Yield()) { Thread.Sleep(1); }` (credits to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383943/switchtothread-vs-sleep1#comment15893576_1383966 ) ? Also note that your code needs `try...finally` for `timeBeginPeriod()` and `timeEndPeriod()`, in order not to break when `Thread.Sleep()` throws an exception.

Answer (score 13):

SpinWait is useful on hyperthreaded processors.  With hyperthreading, multiple OS scheduled threads can be running on the same physical processor, sharing the processor resources.  SpinWait indicates to the processor that you are not doing any useful work and that it should run code from a different logical CPU.  As the name suggests, it is typically used when you are spinning.

Suppose you have code like:

```
while (!foo) {} // Spin until foo is set.
```

If this thread is running on a thread on a hyperthreaded processor, it is consuming processor resources that could be used for other threads running on the processor.

By changing to:

```
while (!foo) {Thread.SpinWait(1);}
```

We are indicating to the CPU to give some resources to the other thread.

SpinWait does not affect OS scheduling of threads.

For your main questions about the "Ultimate Yield", it depends heavily on your situation - you won't be able to get a good answer without clarifying why you want a thread to yield.  From my perspective, the best way to yield the processor is getting the thread to enter a wait state and only waking when there is work to do.  Anything else is just wasting CPU time.

Comment: How is a hyperthreaded processor different from dual core processors? Btw, I implemented the "Ultimate Yield" to hide the implementation details, I obviously still have to consider which yield make the most sense a certain scenario.

Comment: In dual core processors, each core has its own state and execution resources.  Most of the time each core can be viewed as its own distinct CPU, they just share a package.  A hyperthreaded CPU has duplicated state, but not execution resources.  It appears to the OS as multiple CPU's.  There are only finite execute resources on the processor and it switches between the different threads which have been scheduled on it.  Hyperthreading and multicore do exist - you can buy a quad core, hyperthreaded Core i7 prcoessor.  4 cores, 8 runnable threads.

Comment: Yeah, I just did. I was more interested in how Thread.SpinWait could be used in my method than what HyperThreading actually means. For example, would it make sense to add "ThreadYieldTarget.AnyThreadOnHyperThreadedProcessor" and call  Thread.SpinWait(1)?

Comment: No that would not make sense.  SpinWait is primarily used for implementing spinlocks.  You shouldn't think of it as a yield.

Comment: If you don't know what SpinWait does (in detail) you shouldn't think about using it...

Answer (score 6):

The article "How does Locks Lock" by Jeff Moser (http://www.moserware.com/2008/09/how-do-locks-lock.html) can give some inside about the mechanics of SpinWait. To cite the document:

> What exactly is it doing? Looking at
>   Rotor's
>   clr/src/vm/comsynchronizable.cpp gives
>   us the reality:
>
> FCIMPL1(void, ThreadNative::SpinWait, int iterations)
>      {
>       WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
>       STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
>     YieldProcessor();
> ```
>
> }
>      FCIMPLEND
>
> Further diving shows that
>   "YieldProcessor" is this macro:
>
> #define YieldProcessor() __asm { rep nop }
>
> This is a "repeat no-op" assembly
>   instruction. It's also known in the
>   Intel instruction set manual as "PAUSE
>   - Spin Loop Hint." This means that the CPU knows about the spin waiting that
>   we're wanting to accomplish.

Related:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687419(VS.85).aspx
http://www.moserware.com/2008/09/how-do-locks-lock.html#lockfn7

Answer (score 5):

SpinWait is design to wait *without yielding the current timeslice*

It is designed for situations where you know you'll want to do something in a very short time so losing you timeslice will be excessive.

I was under the impression Thread.Yield(x) for any value of x < the thread quantum was equivalent, including zero though I have no benchmarks to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, here are some profiling numbers.

(!) Don't take this profiling too seriously! Is made just to illustrate above answers in numbers and roughly compare magnitude of values.

```
static void Profile(Action func)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var beginTime = DateTime.Now;
        ulong count = 0;
        while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(beginTime).TotalSeconds < 5)
        {
            sw.Start();
            func();
            sw.Stop();
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Made {count} iterations in ~5s. Total sleep time {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}[ms]. Mean time = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/(double) count} [ms]");
    }

        Profile(()=>Thread.Sleep(0));
        Profile(()=>Thread.Sleep(1));
        Profile(()=>Thread.Yield());
        Profile(()=>Thread.SpinWait(1));
```

The results of spinning loops for ~5s:

```
Function   | CPU % | Iters made |  Total sleep  | Invoke 
           |       |            |  time [ms]    | time [ms]
===================================================================== 
Sleep(0)   | 100 0 | 2318103    | 482           | 0.00020
Sleep(1)   |  6  0 | 4586       | 5456          | 1.08971 
Yield()    | 100 0 | 2495220    | 364           | 0.00010
SpinWait(1)| 100 0 | 2668745    | 81            | 0.00003
```

Made with Mono 4.2.3 x86_64