# How long is a single spin in ManualResetEventSlim

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

How long is a single spin in c#? What I want to know is there is a ManualResetEventSlim that has a spinCount parameter and I want to know how long each spin is in milliseconds or how it works? I know spinning is more efficient for short waits than a kernel wait. So I am just trying to see what I should set this value to for a job that generally takes 2-10 sec.

Comment: 2-10 .. what?  Did you mean microseconds?

Comment: Spinning is in nanoseconds and you simply don't do it for 2-10 seconds... not even for 2-10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no correlation between `spinCount` parameter in the constructor and the number of milliseconds spent doing a spin wait.

Here is how it works. MRES uses this `spinCount` parameter to go through its own waiting routine independent of `Thread.SpinWait`.

- The first 10 iterations alternate between calling `Thread.Yield` and `Thread.SpinWait`. The call to `Thread.SpinWait` starts with a spin of `Environment.ProcessorCount * 4` and then approximately doubles on each successive call.
- Thereafter each iteration divisible by 20 calls `Thread.Sleep(1)`.
- Otherwise those divisible by 5 call `Thread.Sleep(0)`.
- Otherwise `Thread.Yield` is called.
- The `CancellationToken` is checked every 10 iterations after 100.

So as you can see there is a fairly complex song-and-dance going on inside MRES's custom spinning routine. And the algorithm could change from version to version. There is really no way to predict how long each spin will last.

If your typical wait times are 2-10 seconds then your code is almost certainly going to do a kernel level wait via `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` coordinations because the `spinCount` parameter is limited to 2047 anyway.

Plus, 2-10 seconds is a long time. Do you really want to spin that long?

Comment: +1 for interesting details.  It tries really hard to get the other thread to release the lock!

Comment: Post away, as long as you don't expect me to answer it <g>  I would like to know too.  On the odd occasions that I've used sleep(0)/sleep(1), (debugging only), I've seen no difference in performance.

Comment: @Gabe - it doubles on iteration 1,2,3,4,7,8,9. It does a Yield instead of a SpinWait on iteration 5. On iteration 6 it increases *4.

Comment: I kinda get it but not completely but whatever I will spin for 10 cycles and let it do kernel mutex.

Comment: @Gabe: Yeah, hatchet is right. I said "approximately" because the formula was `ProcessorCount * (4 << iteration)` but the iterations are not necessarily sequential. By the way, there is some pretty thick code in there. I'd like to know how Microsoft came up with that.

Comment: @MartinJames: No need for me to post that question. [Someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1413630/158779) beat me to it a long time ago.

Answer (score 13):

Spin count is meant to be small. The default is 10 (or 1 if running on a single processor). If you use the constructor that lets you specify the spin count, the max allowed is 2047. If the event is not signaled very quickly, the ManualResetEventSlim uses a regular event handle wait. As @HenkHolterman mentioned, the times involved are far, far more tiny than seconds. We're talking cycles, not seconds or even milliseconds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbefs30.aspx

> In the .NET Framework version 4, you can use the
>   System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim class for better performance
>   when wait times are expected to be very short, and when the event does
>   not cross a process boundary. ManualResetEventSlim uses busy spinning
>   for a short time while it waits for the event to become signaled. When
>   wait times are short, spinning can be much less expensive than waiting
>   by using wait handles. However, if the event does not become signaled
>   within a certain period of time, ManualResetEventSlim resorts to a
>   regular event handle wait.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee722114.aspx

> On multicore computers, when a resource is not expected to be held
>   for long periods of time, it can be more efficient for a waiting
>   thread to spin in user mode for a few dozen or a few hundred cycles,
>   and then retry to acquire the resource. If the resource is available
>   after spinning, then you have saved several thousand cycles. If the
>   resource is still not available, then you have spent only a few cycles
>   and can still enter a kernel-based wait.

EDIT: To answer your question directly though, the length of time for a single spin cannot be answered definitively, because it depends upon the hardware on which it's running.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait(v=vs.95).aspx

> SpinWait essentially puts the processor into a very tight loop, with
>   the loop count specified by the iterations parameter. The duration of
>   the wait therefore depends on the speed of the processor.