# ManualResetEventSlim recommended wait time

Tags: c#, multithreading, manualresetevent

The MSDN documentation for `ManualResetEventSlim` states

> You can use this class for better performance than `ManualResetEvent` when wait times are expected to be very short.

How long is "very short"? At what point will the benefit of using a kernel object with a `ManualResetEvent` outweigh the overhead of instantiating it?

Comment: For me, "very short" is pretty meaningless. My rule is that if I expect the event to be set most of the time (i.e. I expect no wait), then I'll use `ManualResetEventSlim`. Otherwise I'll use `ManualResetEvent`. If you're writing a performance sensitive application, you should test your code with both to determine if there's any difference. If you're not counting microseconds, then it's probably a waste of time to worry about which one is faster.

Comment: "Very short" in this context means tens- to hundreds-of microseconds. The slim version spin-waits with the expectation that the other thread will release the lock in less time than a couple of context switches would take.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I found and would love for someone else to validate this, but this is what I found while reading the [Reference Source for ManualResetEventSlim](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs#07ccbd30abe2a211)

**ManualResetEventSlim**
It is attempting to just sleep and yield based on the number of processors and doing extremely short sleeps -- 1ms or 0ms depending on its current spin index. If it still hasn't been enough time, it will then revert to using `Monitor.Wait` using a new updated version of the timeout that was originally passed in.

*Passing in 0 for Thread.Sleep relieves its time slice.*

**ManualResetEvent**
It uses `WaitHandle` and calls native methods to handle waiting for the specified time. Unfortunately, I am unable to see what it is doing.

**My Conclusion**
"Very Short" means just a few milliseconds.

**EDIT:** I just found these which have lots of information:

- [How long is a single spin in ManualResetEventSlim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304854/how-long-is-a-single-spin-in-manualreseteventslim)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ce62320-68fe-4d07-8576-f30a0325a68c/when-to-use-manualreseteventslim?forum=parallelextensions

Answer (score 0):

The scale from CPU cache to RAM and to Kernel is approximately logarithmic. Say you can do 400 cycles using CPU cache or 20 CPU cycles using reading / writing RAM or 1 kernel operation. The numbers will depend on hardware, it's just an estimate.

If you think that maximum wait times will be less than 6-15 ns (~20-50 CPU cycles @ 3GHz) than it's a small wait time.