# How to add a Git submodule from a shared directory over network?

Tags: git, git-submodules, shared-directory

I have a shared directory on a computer in LAN which contains a Git repository. Now I am trying to add it as a submodule to one of my repositories.

I have tried :

```
git.exe submodule add -- \\Remote-PC\SharedDirectory\module1 module1
```

But when I run this command, it fails with the following error :

```
repo URL: '\\Remote-PC\SharedDirectory\module1' must be absolute or begin with ./|../
```

I don't know why it gives this error. Is it possible to add a shared directory as a submodule?

Comment: Why the `--`? It's not the issue, I'm just not sure why you'd need it.

Comment: @Gauthier Actually I am using SmartGit and the command is the one that SmartGit generates when the wizard of adding a submodule is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "[git on UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4998549/6309)", you have the choice between:

- bind the UNC path as a network drive
- try and use `/`: `//Remote-PC/SharedDirectory/module1`
- <del>escape the backslash: `\\\\Remote-PC\\SharedDirectory\\module1`</del> (the OP reports it doesn't work for him)

For performance, [make sure to use a Git 2.1+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974690/6309) (as in [git for Windows 2.4.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/))

Comment: Your second approach works, but the third one does not work. It gives the same error.